# How to prevent Gatsby image from blurring a logo with every reload?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I've read through the gatsby-image docs but can't figure out how to turn something off. By default, it seems gatsby-image loads a thumbnail of an image, then loads the image progressively. Basically a nice placeholder effect. But I find that my logo keeps blurring everytime I change pages. Here's my code:

```
 <StaticQuery
            query={graphql`
              query {
                file(relativePath: { eq: "appendto_logo.png" }) {
                  childImageSharp {
                    # Specify the image processing specifications right in the query.
                    # Makes it trivial to update as your page's design changes.
                    fixed(width: 150) {
                      ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            `}
            render={data => <Img fixed={data.file.childImageSharp.fixed} />}
          />
```

Any thoughts? How to prevent that blurring effect? Or the thumbnail loading effect...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Switching to `GatsbyImageSharpFixed_noBase64` solved it (instead of just  `...GatsbyImageSharpFixed`)

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

`critical` is now deprecated in favor of `loading`:

```
 - <Img critical fixed={ ... } />
 + <Img loading="eager" fixed={ ... } />
```

Also use `_noBase64` sharp fragments to completely remove the blur effect, as @epsilon42's comment & Kyle's answer suggested.

And finally, to persist a component (navigation bar, etc.) between page load, you can wrap the pages in a layout with that component.

---

**Original answer**

I think you can pass in a `critical` prop to Gatsby Image, like this: `<Img critical fixed={ ... }>` It will always load the image immediately. You might want to add `fadeIn` in there as well:

> Images marked as critical will start loading immediately as the DOM is parsed, but unless fadeIn is set to false, the transition from placeholder to final image will not occur until after the component is mounted.

[Gatsby Image docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/)

Comment: Hmmm...No dice on that one...wondering what other attribute it could be.

Comment: `critical` worked for me to remove the blur effect - the only exception to this was when the logo first loads, but navigation to all other pages after this did not display the blur animation. FYI: the prop `critical` is now deprecated in favour of `loading={`eager`}`. However, the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/@dylanvann/gatsby-image/) recommend using a fragment with `_noBase64` at the end

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the blurring effect you could just hide the placeholder using the `placeholderStyle` attribute:

`<Img fixed={data.logoImage.childImageSharp.fixed} placeholderStyle={{ visibility: "hidden" }}/>`

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found with the new gatsby-image package is to query the image with a `placeholder` parameter like this:

```
logos {
  localFile {
    childImageSharp {
      gatsbyImageData(placeholder: NONE)
    }
  }
}
```